# Why twitter-bootstrap doesn't use an image but <span class="icon-bar"></span>?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Boostrap3 uses this code to make a toggle button within a navbar in mobile view, but why don't just use a image instead of empty elements?

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: When you look closely you realize `icon-bar` does not show any image at all. Maybe that's why it's not `<img>`?

Comment: You can change the color of img from css. But you can change color for <span> and also apply other css properties you won't otherwise be able to apply to img. Also have you ever seen what happens to a webpage when an img does not load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely to maintain a "forward" thinking approach to web design. There's no reason to make an unnecessary media request if the same visual effect can be achieved using only html and css. Similarly, the advancement in css has allowed transitions that were once only possible with javascript or flash.

If you inspect the html of that mobile menu icon, it is pretty apparent what it is doing and how the loading of even a small image takes more processing than a small amount of markup. Succinctly, it is just a better approach at modern design.

Comment: Better experience is more important than "separation of structure and presentation" in Bootstrap, right?:)

Comment: maybe they figure that the best experience here is to have the appearance reflect (or impose) a particular web standard by making it part of the structure.